# Add y-axis label to ctree plot

Tags: r, plot

I'm building a regression tree using `ctree` from the `party` package. How can I add a y-axis label to only the box plot on the far left?

For example, I'd like to print 'Ozone' just to the left of the Node 3 plot produced by the example code below.

```
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
airct <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = airq, 
           controls = ctree_control(maxsurrogate = 3))
airct
plot(airct)
```

[image: example plot]

I've tried `text` and `grid.text`, but I can't get labels to show up on the plot using either approach.

Comment: @Jota that works perfectly. If you add as an answer, I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mtext`

```
plot.new()
plot(airct)
mtext(text = "Ozone", side = 2, srt = 90, padj = -4, adj = 0)
```

`side = 2` puts it on the left margin.  `srt = 90` rotates the text 90 degrees. `padj = -4` moves the text to the left (perpendicular adjustment), and `adj = 0` is for left or bottom alignment.  See ?mtext for more details about the adjustments.

[image]

Comment: This suggestion works, but I'm having trouble with saving the figure. I'm getting `Error : invalid graphics state`, which I think has to do with calling `plot.new()`? I've tried to save the figure in a few ways (point and click in RStudio, also `jpeg()`, and I continue to get the same error.

Comment: @JessicaBeyer Hm.... here's what I did to save the plot:  `png("so.png"); plot.new(); plot(airct); mtext(text = "Ozone", side = 2, srt = 90, padj = -4, adj = 0); dev.off()`.  That doesn't work for you?  Using `jpeg(); ... ; dev.off()` shouldn't be any different.  I had to call `plot.new()` to get `mtext` to work properly, though.

Comment: Thanks- that worked. I'm not sure what I had done wrong the first time (maybe called something out of order?), but that took care of it.